# (scala) Gatling headerRegex throws implicit value exception

Tags: scala, implicit, gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to run gatling test where it logs in and checks and store the value of a cookie.

Here's the code snippet that I have:

```
.pause(minWait, maxWait)
            .feed(usernames)
            .exec(
                http("_pLoginForm_Basic")
                    .post("${postUrl}")
                    .headers(headers_0)
                    .formParam("username", "${username}")
                    .formParam("password", "test123")
                    .check(status.is(200),
                        headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "viafoura_session_id")
                            .ofType[(String, String)]
                            .saveAs("vf_sess_id")
                    )
            );
```

The login and status check part is working fine, but *headerRegex* always give me the following error during execution:

```
07:55:03.140 [main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:141] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - /home/crengga/projects/vi-vinl/vinl-gatling/src/test/scala/nl/vi/gatling/simulation/OpenSessionsInitializer.scala:63: could not find implicit value for parameter extractorFactory: io.gatling.http.check.header.HttpHeaderRegexExtractorFactory
```

Am I missing some imports in my gatling (scala) class?

I have been searching on the internet about the error, but so far I could  find are general Scala posts (not gatling specific), and my knowledge of scala is limited.

Comment: Hey, could you please try to remove _.ofType[(String, String)]_ from the code and check if the error still appears?

Comment: Yes the error still appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was turns out to be wrong way of importing the classes. Since I relied on intellij's auto import, it did not import all needed classes.

Previously was like this:

```
import io.gatling.http.Predef.{currentLocationRegex, headerRegex, http, regex, responseTimeInMillis, status}
```

And I changed it to

```
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
```